# What does alpha.disabled mean in Spark's ButtonSkin in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex-spark

Take the following code from spark.skins.spark.ButtonSkin.mxml:

```
<s:SparkButtonSkin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
         xmlns:fb="http://ns.adobe.com/flashbuilder/2009"
         minWidth="21" minHeight="21" 
         alpha.disabled="0.5">
```

What does `alpha.disabled` mean?  Because alpha is a Number-type getter in class mx.core.UIComponent, and Numbers don't have a property called `disabled`.  Even if they did, I've never seen a property of a getter being set to something in an MXML element tag before, at least that I can remember.

I've tried to look in a couple of other spots to find what's going on there, but what does setting `alpha.disabled` like this mean?  What construct of the language is being used here?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a reference to the "new" state syntax introduced in Flex 4.0.  It means that when the state of the component is set to disabled the alpha property will be 0.5 .  Otherwise the alpha state will be the default value--which I I assume 1.

When creating my own components; and using this approach, I like to specify values for every state.  Sometimes I use the 'catch' all.  Like this:

```
<s:SparkButtonSkin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
         xmlns:fb="http://ns.adobe.com/flashbuilder/2009"
         minWidth="21" minHeight="21" 
         alpha="0.7"
         alpha.normal="1"
         alpha.disabled="0.5"
>
```

The above code means that in the disabled state the alpha property will be 0.5.  In the normal state the alpha will be 1.  In all other states the alpha will be 0.7.

The 'state' name after the property can also refer to a state group instead of an explicit state.

Comment: It's new syntax in Flex 4.0?  Does that mean this syntax is basically just related to MXML/Flex?  What does it map to in AS3?

Comment: @Panzercrisis Yes it's MXML only and it maps to a whole lot of AS  stuff you don't want to care about. But basically the component sets up event listeners for [state change](http://flex.apache.org/asdoc/mx/events/StateChangeEvent.html#CURRENT_STATE_CHANGE) events and sets the property's value (alpha in this case) to the value that is mapped to a specific state or stategroup (0.7 by default, 1 in the 'normal' state, etc. in Reboog711's example). The "new" (I wouldn't call 5 years old "new", but anyway) state syntax is one of the most powerful features of Flex 4.